# Получение почты на собственный сервер

Tags: exim, dovecot, exim4

Есть связка exim4+dovecot+mysql+postfixadmin+roundcube. На данный момент письма отправляются без каких либо проблем, как от сервера, так и от roundcube. Авторизация на roundcube проходит хорошо. Пароли используют CRAM-MD5. Почтовые ящики создавал через postfixadmin. На данный момент всё работает, кроме получения почты. При отправки почты на почту сервера admin@domain на email, с которого отправляли пишет: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender. В exim4 пишет: 550 Unrouteable address.
Подскажите, как решить проблему? В интернете много перечитал информации, но так и не осилил. Может exim4 не видит почтовые ящики, которые были созданы postfixadmin?

Comment: Причина недоставки обычно указана в возвратном письме, которое «returning message to sender”. Ищите ответ в нем.

Comment: Всё что пишет:  SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<admin@domain>:
    550 Unrouteable address

Comment: Письма же приходят на 25 порт, верно? А на 25 порту exim4 висит. Может какие-то настройки упустил не знаю, в интернете смотрел, всё верно.

Comment: mx-запись куда указывает?

Comment: Как посмотреть, куда указывает?

Comment: В личной кабинете управления доменом в DNS записях у меня вообще нет MX записей. Там только A и TXT. Если нужно MX запись написать там же, то в каком формате? domain MX ip ?